# How to search for a file from the list of installed files of each package installed in the system

Tags: debian, command-line, apt, package-management, synaptic

`Synaptic` has the option to search from different sources (Package name, description, name and description, etc)... But if you have a package installed in your system, Synaptic can show you what files are attached to that installation.

So, **what command can extract the list of all files generated by all installed packages to search on it?**

For example, yesterday I wanted to know which packags have been installed ICC profiles in my system, but I have to do it manually (with Synaptic filters) reading all installed files of each installed packages... I don't know if there are more `.ICC`.

The sample output of the command I'm requesting is:

```bsh
$ ./search --show-origin --show-package '*.icc'
buster-backports    krita          /usr/share/colors/icc/krita/cmyk.icc
buster              colord         /usr/share/colors/icc/colord/sRGB.icc
bullseye            ghostscript    /usr/share/colors/icc/ghostscript/ps_cmyk.icc
```

Comment: See also `(cd /var/lib/dpkg/info && grep '\.icc$' *.list)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could search for filenames in packages with `dpkg -S`:

> ```
>           -S, --search filename-search-pattern...
>               Search for a filename from installed packages.
> ```

```
$ dpkg -S '*.icc'
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/x11-colors.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/lab.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/scrgb.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Gamma6500K.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/esrgb.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/CIE-RGB.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Gamma5000K.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/ProPhotoRGB.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/EktaSpacePS5.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/ECI-RGBv2.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/srgb.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/sgray.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/BetaRGB.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/ps_rgb.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/AppleRGB.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/default_gray.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/BruceRGB.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Gamma5500K.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/a98.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/ps_gray.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Rec709.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/default_rgb.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/AdobeRGB1998.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/WideGamutRGB.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/default_cmyk.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/ECI-RGBv1.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/sRGB.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/NTSC-RGB.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/BestRGB.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/DonRGB4.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/ColorMatchRGB.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/SwappedRedAndGreen.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Bluish.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/rommrgb.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/gray_to_k.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/PAL-RGB.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Crayons.icc
colord-data: /usr/share/color/icc/colord/SMPTE-C-RGB.icc
libgs9-common: /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/ps_cmyk.icc
```

Comment: Ok, it's incredibly fast! - Thank you!
Now I will try to make a script based on it to get more useful behaviors.